# SQL Server trigger - select random ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, triggers

I am going to write a trigger which inserts a row into a table. The insert statement includes an `ID` column. I want my trigger to randomly choose one out of three IDs to insert, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RAND` function to generate a random number such that `i <= x < j`.

```
 FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i))
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) you can find the documentation on the `RAND` function.